# Is there a way to get turtles to move at specific speeds (not integer numbers)?

Tags: python, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

I am doing a project where different turtles race around an oval track, but I am comparing them to actual world record times it takes to move around the track. I therefore am looking for a way to get the turtles to moves at more specific speeds. I have done turtle.speed(), but it only takes integer values. Perhaps a way to get them to move a certain number of pixels per second? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

We can turn off animation and use timer events to control the speed of the turtle.  In the example below, the turtle moves at a rate of roughly 100 pixels per second (i.e. 5 pixels every 50 milliseconds):

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle

screen = Screen()
screen.tracer(False)

turtle = Turtle('turtle')

def move():
    if turtle.xcor() < screen.window_width()/2:
        turtle.forward(5)  # move forward 5 pixels
        screen.update()
        screen.ontimer(move, 50)  # repeat in 50 milliseconds

move()

screen.exitonclick()
```

Other turtles can be programmed to move at different rates within the same program.